# LLaMA-Factory : Trying to run a fine-tuned model with evaluate.py(mmlu) but I get TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType

Tags: llama

I'm currently attempting to evaluate a fine-tuned model with MMLU using LLaMa-Factory. While I can successfully evaluate the model with meta-llama/Llama-2-7b-chat-hf, which is supported by LLaMa-Factory, I encounter errors when trying to evaluate other models.

Is there any way I can evaluate other models using LLaMa-Factory?

*** The beomi model works great by itself, however it doesn't work with llama-factory

```
(llama_factory) causer@ca-14:~/data/LLaMA-Factory$ 
CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=1 python      src/evaluate.py --model_name_or_path beomi/llama-2-ko-7b --task minimmlu --split test --lang en --n_shot 5 --batch_size 1 --template llama2


[INFO|tokenization_utils_base.py:2046] 2024-03-01 
17:37:53,436 >> loading file tokenizer_config.json 
from cache at 
/home/causer/.cache/huggingface/hub/models--beomi-- 
llama-2-ko-7b/snapshots/4709f8cd6074590ed591e2fdf75499ae76ac4064/toke 
 nizer_config.json[INFO|tokenization_utils_base.py:2046] 
2024-03-01 17:37:53,436 >> loading file tokenizer.json from cache at /home/causer/.cache/huggingface/hub/models--beomi--llama-2-ko-7b/snapshots/4709f8cd6074590ed591e2fdf75499ae76ac4064/tokenizer.jsonTraceback (most recent call last):File "/home/causer/data/LLaMA-Factory/src/evaluate.py", line 
10, in <module>main()File "/home/causer/data/LLaMA-Factory/src/evaluate.py", line 5, in mainevaluator = Evaluator()File "/home/causer/data/LLaMA-Factory/src/llmtuner/eval/evaluator.py", line 24, in initself.model, self.tokenizer = load_model_and_tokenizer(self.model_args, finetuning_args)File "/home/causer/data/LLaMA-Factory/src/llmtuner/model/loader.py", line 44, in load_model_and_tokenizertokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(File "/home/causer/anaconda3/envs/llama_factory/lib/python3.10/site-packages/transformers/models/auto/tokenization_auto.py", line 825, in from_pretrainedreturn tokenizer_class.from_pretrained(pretrained_model_name_or_path, *inputs, **kwargs)File "/home/causer/anaconda3/envs/llama_factory/lib/python3.10/site-packages/transformers/tokenization_utils_base.py", line 2048, in from_pretrainedreturn cls._from_pretrained(File "/home/causer/anaconda3/envs/llama_factory/lib/python3.10/site-packages/transformers/tokenization_utils_base.py", line 2287,     in _from_pretrainedtokenizer = 
cls(*init_inputs, **init_kwargs)File "/home/causer/anaconda3/envs/llama_factory/lib/python3.10/site-
```

packages/transformers/models/llama/tokenization_llama.py", line 182, in initself.sp_model = self.get_spm_processor(kwargs.pop("from_slow", False))File "/home/causer/anaconda3/envs/llama_factory/lib/python3.10/site-

packages/transformers/models/llama/tokenization_llama.py", line 212, in get_spm_processorwith open(self.vocab_file,
"rb") as f:TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType`

- I confirmed if there is all the files on the .cache folder
- I confirmed if the model works or not